# New mail server can't send emails, only receives

Tags: postfix, smtp

I'm setting up a new mail server for my company with `Ubuntu Server 11.04` and postfix/dovecot.  I'm new on this so I have some problems. I'm getting it works only for receving mails from any address outside the lan and I can send only for the same domain. If I try to send a new message with it to an outside address (eg gmail) I have `Relay denied`.

So, my server had 2 network interface, 1 for my lan (192.168.1.xxx) and one had a public static ip address. My domain, for testing pourpose, is `enti.centropaghe.it` and I create an `MX` record to `mail.enti.centropaghe.it`

My goal is to get a full functionaly imap/smtp/pop3 server, with autentication on both side and it can send email to all address:)

I post some of my configuration file so you can digg it:

### /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

mydomain = enti.centropaghe.it
myhostname = mail.enti.centropaghe.it
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, localhost
relayhost = $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.1.0/24
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = $mydomain
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
default_transport = error
relay_transport = error
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail/
```

### /etc/resolv.conf

```
search enti.centropaghe.it
nameserver 192.168.1.221 #is my dns server on my lan
```

### /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
192.168.1.148   mail.enti.centropaghe.it darwin
```

### dig enti.centropaghe.it mx

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> enti.centropaghe.it mx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 65356
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;enti.centropaghe.it.           IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
enti.centropaghe.it.    8381    IN      MX      10 mail.enti.centropaghe.it.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
centropaghe.it.         71334   IN      NS      dns2.telemar.it.
centropaghe.it.         71334   IN      NS      dns.telemar.it.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.enti.centropaghe.it. 7333  IN      A       213.178.198.62
dns.telemar.it.         28595   IN      A       213.178.196.1
dns2.telemar.it.        20154   IN      A       213.178.195.254

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.221#53(192.168.1.221)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 29 15:24:47 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 151
```

### dig enti.centropaghe.it any

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> enti.centropaghe.it any
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58752
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;enti.centropaghe.it.           IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
enti.centropaghe.it.    8342    IN      MX      10 mail.enti.centropaghe.it.
enti.centropaghe.it.    7266    IN      A       213.178.198.58

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
centropaghe.it.         71295   IN      NS      dns2.telemar.it.
centropaghe.it.         71295   IN      NS      dns.telemar.it.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.enti.centropaghe.it. 7294  IN      A       213.178.198.62
dns.telemar.it.         28556   IN      A       213.178.196.1
dns2.telemar.it.        20115   IN      A       213.178.195.254

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.221#53(192.168.1.221)
;; WHEN: Wed Feb 29 15:25:27 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 167
```

### /var/log/mail.log

```
Feb 29 17:11:10 darwin postfix/smtpd[8207]: warning: 213.178.xxx.xxx: hostname ip.213.178.xxx.xxx.telemar.it verification failed: Name or service not known
Feb 29 17:11:10 darwin postfix/smtpd[8207]: connect from unknown[213.178.xxx.xxx]
Feb 29 17:11:10 darwin postfix/smtpd[8207]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[213.178.xxx.xxx]: 554 5.7.1 <username@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<otherusername@enti.centropaghe.it> to=<username@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.1.138]>
Feb 29 17:11:13 darwin postfix/smtpd[8207]: disconnect from unknown[213.178.xxx.xxx]
```

### postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail/
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain, localhost
mydomain = enti.centropaghe.it
myhostname = mail.enti.centropaghe.it
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.1.0/24
myorigin = $mydomain
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

I hope that's all. If you need something else, let me know.

### Update

With last modifications, now using the internal ip address of the smtp I can send email to outside address. But doesn't work using mail.enti.centropaghe.it

Comment: Please remove any and all of the above and replace it with the output of `postconf -n`  and the logs from at least one complete message being handled by postfix, that shows the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Why I have to remove? postconf -n is the output of main.cf so it's the same.

Comment: ...no, of course it isn't. Where are the **logs** ?

Comment: added like you request. What's the differences between main.cf and postconf -n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your main.cf:

**default_transport (default: smtp)** You used: *default_transport = error*

> The default mail delivery transport and next-hop destination for destinations that do not match $mydestination, $inet_interfaces, $proxy_interfaces, $virtual_alias_domains, $virtual_mailbox_domains, or $relay_domains

Well, that does it. Remove this line. You want to use SMTP to send out email that isn't for your domain. Right now, you've forced yourself to only perform local delivery (any mail that is supposed to go anywhere outside of that machine will not be accepted). That's why you can receive mail, but nothing that isn't accepted by that host is forwarded.

---

**relayhost (default: empty)** You used: *relayhost = $mydomain*

> The next-hop destination of non-local mail; overrides non-local domains in recipient addresses. This information is overruled with relay_transport...

This definitely affects things. Unless you have a different SMTP server listening on enti.centropaghe.it that you want all mail to go through, your mail is again going nowhere. You probably should remove this line.

---

**relay_transport (default: relay)** You used: *relay_transport = error*

> The default mail delivery transport and next-hop destination for remote delivery to domains listed with $relay_domains. In order of decreasing precedence, the nexthop destination is taken from $relay_transport, $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps, $relayhost, or from the recipient domain

I see no $relay_domains, so I suggest removing this.

### Update

Ah, horse of a different color. This line below says who is allowed to relay. Your error message is coming from a host beginning with `213.178`. Since there is no entry for it and you have other form of authentication for relaying, it is denied. Perhaps you want to add an entry covering your assigned network range?

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.1.0/24
```

Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: `default_transport=error` means that *any* outgoing mail will be rejected (5xx) and returned to sender. It's a bit more disastrous than "only allowing local delivery", which is really not the result this has.

Comment: @adaptr Oops, I see how I conveyed that the wrong way. I was thinking local as in machine, one machine for domain, only receipt there... fixing it so my wording isn't confusing. Thanks.

Comment: As I indicated above, the mail **is** *accepted*; when postfix tries to deliver it, this causes a rejection on the transport level, and the message is **bounced**.

Comment: @JeffFerland I tried with your modification but I still have the same error, relay denied when I try to use the smtp for sending to other address. The incoming mail work well. I add a log entry for the message that it can't deliver

Comment: Another thing. I try to connect from the lan to the smtp internal address, and from inside the lan I can send the emails to outside address. It doesn't work only using mail.enti.centropaghe.it

Comment: @Kreker See update. Your log shows that you're connecting from a public IP in that case and that IP is not part of your configured hosts for relaying.

Comment: @JeffFerland Yes. I want that everybody from anywhere can connect to the mail server, so every ip can relay but with authentication of course for not becoming a spammer heaven:). In fact if I add my adsl's ip to mynetwork, everything works like a charm. What I have to write to accept every ip?

Comment: @Kreker see http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html for a howto on setting up authentication in Postfix.

Comment: @JeffFerland a testing authetication method (STARTTLS) already working (I think:)). There is a fast way to accept all the ips? Just for testing and for see that all works:) thanks

Comment: @Kreker Accepting mail from all IP addresses without authentication will turn you into a source of spam in seconds. Quite literally, somebody will probably determine that you're an open relay in under a minute. Limit only to addresses you know are OK.

Comment: @JeffFerland I don't understand this thing. I don't want to limit only to addresses that I know because it's impossible. I have circumstances where somebody has to connect from phone or from customer. So what's the problem on been open for all IPs and enable the autentication like now? I'm not an open relay with this method. So what I have to set in mynetwork for accept for all ips? I don't find anything in google and postfix documentation

Comment: You disallow submission over port 25 and uncomment the dedicated submission listener in master.cf, then enforce TLS and SASL on that port.

Comment: You don't "open for all IPs"... and this may just be us trying to say the same thing in different words. Postfix will relay ((authenticated clients) or (my networks hosts)). As long as one of them is true, you're ok. My point is that you should not add the whole internet to my networks. As adaptr pointed out, some folks setup the config across different ports and use 587. http://www.google.com/search?q=smtp+port+587

Comment: I really don't understand you guys:)....I repeat....I can't know the ip address that my customers and my co-workers had when they try to connect for sending emails. And I don't understand why I'm not safe if any IPs can connect to my smtp providing a valid username/password!

Comment: You must allow any IP to connect because any IP could be sending mail that is destined to you. The check for whether relaying is allowed happens in the middle of the conversation and only if there is mail that is meant for somewhere else. If somebody authenticates they can use you to relay mail elsewhere regardless of where they came from.

Comment: Ok sorry, now I understand. It's for my english's fault:).